# Selecting a dropdown menu in Safari

Tags: applescript, safari

I need to create an Applescript to open a certain website and export it as PDF using the menu "Save as PDF…" under the File menu. Then, I need to save that PDF on a certain location on my hard drive. I am encountering trouble trying to activate the dropdown menu in the first place.

I am trying this code but I get an error:

```
tell application "Safari" to open location "http://www.webiste.com/"
delay 1
    click menu item "Save as PDF..." of menu bar item "File"        
    end tell
end tell
```

I am adding a delay 1 to make sure all elements are loaded before firing the "Save as PDF..." menu.
I haven't yet reached the point of determining the specific location where I want that PDF to be stored.
I will use Automator to create a recurring event based on this apple script.
Any ideas?

Comment: My menu says Export as PDF, not Save. It also has an ellipsis … not three stops ... [there is a distinct difference].

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is "Export as PDF..." I corrected the ellipsis too but still getting the error on the words *menu item*: Syntax Error: Expected end of line, etc. but found class name.

Comment: My Applescript it s bit rusty. I'd set a key command to the menu item instead, then all you need to do with the script is hit the key combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppleScript doesn't know about menu items, so you will need to use an application that does, such as **System Events**.  Menus can get confusing since menu items can also have menus (take a look at the scripting dictionary), but your command would look something like:

```
tell application "Safari"
   open location "http://www.website.com/" -- this command is from Standard Additions
   activate -- bring Safari to the front if it isn't already
end tell
delay 2
tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Export as PDF…" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Safari"
```

Comment: Thank you, red_manace. The only issue I had was this: "System Events got an error: Script Editor is not allowed assistive access". I Only hade to add access in the Accessibility tab to the Script Editor app. Now I need to figure out how to set the destination path and then press the "save button" in the dialog. –

Answer (score 2):

Tested under **macOS High Sierra**, here is how I do it:

```applescript
set saveToLocation to "~/Documents"
set myURL to "http://www.webiste.com/"

tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:myURL}
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists (buttons of ¬
        UI elements of ¬
        groups of ¬
        toolbar 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        process "Safari" whose ¬
        name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    tell application process "Safari"
        click menu item "Export as PDF…" of ¬
            menu "File" of ¬
            menu bar item "File" of ¬
            menu bar 1
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of window 1
            delay 0.05
        end repeat
        keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down}
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
            delay 0.05
        end repeat
        set value of ¬
            combo box 1 of ¬
            sheet 1 of ¬
            sheet 1 of ¬
            window 1 to ¬
            saveToLocation
        click button "Go" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
        click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Will try to work around your idea. Thank you so much!